# TwitterOAuth Api "get sign in btn"

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I want only get the link for "connect a user to my twitter app".

here's my code :

```
<?php

require_once "../../../utils/UtilsIncluder.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

session_start();

$consumer_key = 'something';
$consumer_secret = 'somethingother';
$callback = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/front/index.html";

$oauth = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$content = $oauth->oauth("request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>$callback]);

var_dump($content);

echo "<a href='".$content."'>Authorize our app</a>";
```

The big probleme is that not work, i didn't get a link for this. So i tried some other things like :

```
$content = $oauth->oauth2("request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>$callback]); // display => null
$content = $oauth->url("request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>$callback]); // display https://api.twitter.com/request_token?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Ffront%2F1_index.html => but onclick twitter says to me "page not found"
$content = $oauth->oauth("1.1/request_token", "oauth_callback"=>$callback]); // display => page not found by twitter
$content = $oauth->oauth("1/request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>$callback]); // display => "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1" ... what did i tried before ? ..
$content = $oauth->get("request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>callback]); // display => Sorry, that page does not exist
$content = $oauth->post("request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>callback]); // display => Sorry, that page does not exist
$content = $oauth->oauth("request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>callback]); // display => page not found
```

EDIT :

```
$content = $oauth->oauth("oauth/request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>callback]); // display => Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message 'Request token failed'
$content = $oauth->post("oauth/request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>callback]); // display => Sorry, that page does not exist
$content = $oauth->oauth2("oauth/request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>callback]); // display => Bad Authentication data.
$content = $oauth->oauth("1.1/oauth/request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>$callback]); // display Bad Authentication data.
$content = $oauth->post("1.1/oauth/request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>$callback]); // display => Sorry, that page does not exist
$content = $oauth->oauth2("1.1/oauth/request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>$callback]); // display => Sorry, that page does not exist
```

`$oauth->oauth("oauth/request_token"` seems to be interesting so i tried :

```
try {
    $content = $oauth->oauth("oauth/request_token", ["oauth_callback"=>$callback]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
// display => Request token failed (thx for details ^^)
```

Hum, maybe i make a thing wrong ? Has someone a working example with TwitterOAuth that is working for getting a redirect link ?

Comment: I believe the path (first parameter) should be `"oauth/request_token"`

Comment: @PatrickQ i updated my question, doesn't work better :/

Comment: @PatrickQ according to source code from oauth fonction :  "Make /oauth/* requests to the API." theorically i don't need to specify "oauth/"

Comment: Okay.  I've never used that library.  I was just basing my suggestion on the example given for the `oauth()` function about half-way down the page [here](https://twitteroauth.com/)

Comment: Right, maybe i miss understand the doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 
I saw that i must specify my callback url in the twitter app to (https://apps.twitter.com/app). Now it's working perfectly.

[image]